# Java Time between Date and Now

Tags: java, date, time

I need help writing a function in Java that takes an input date and tells me the number of years, months, and days since the date.

For example, "July 1, 2005" would output "6 years, 2 months, 2 days"

Comment: Have you made any attempt? what are you struggling with? have you written it out in pseudocode?

Comment: You'll see this type of feature already implemented by a number of great libraries, such as [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Based on what? You said 6 years but what's the base date?

Comment: @Braveyard - it says in the title, 'between Date and Now'

Comment: @Richard - Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a "Do my work for me" site. You will want to actually do some research, attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then ask here if you're stuck and need specific help. People will be more than willing to assist at that point.

Comment: Oh that's simple `Calendar` operation... did you try deduction?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense without a specific Locale, TimeZone and Calendar.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - it makes it relatively easy:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LocalDate then = new LocalDate(2005, 7, 1);
        LocalDate today = new LocalDate();

        Period period = new Period(then, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
        System.out.println(period); // P6Y2M2D
        System.out.println(period.getYears()); // 6
        System.out.println(period.getMonths()); // 2
        System.out.println(period.getDays()); //2
    }
}
```

(I *vastly* prefer the Joda API to `Date`/`Calendar`. It's much easier to use, partly due to generally preferring immutability.)

Comment: Does Joda-Time supports Java version 1.4.2?

Comment: @Kit: You may need to find a 1.x version - 2.0 uses generics etc, so required Java 1.5 or higher I believe.

Comment: To make it even easier, look to the [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) class. For example, a formatter that prints years and months, like "15 years and 8 months", can be constructed as follows:

`PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .printZeroAlways()
     .appendYears()
     .appendSuffix(" year", " years")
     .appendSeparator(" and ")
     .printZeroRarelyLast()
     .appendMonths()
     .appendSuffix(" month", " months")
     .toFormatter();`

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

You can use [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2005, 7, 1);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2011, 9, 3);
        Period period = startDate.until(endDate);
        System.out.println(period);

        // Custom format
        String formatted = String.format("%d years, %d months, %d days", period.getYears(), period.getMonths(),
                period.getDays());
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
P6Y2M2D
6 years, 2 months, 2 days
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mVvprc)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>